# bootstrap popover button click event does not working using jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, popover, bootstrap-popover

I use the code for bootstrap popover as follows,

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" rel="popover"  data-placement="top"
                        data-original-title="<i class='fa fa-fw fa-users'></i> Enter New Investor Group"
                        data-content="<div class='smart-form'><div class='col-sm-10'><label class='input'><input type='text' name='NewInvestor' placeholder='Investor Group Name' id='NewInvestor' /></label></div><div class='col-sm-2'><button id='btntest' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm assignedGroup' type='button' data-target-id='NewInvestor' >ADD</button></div></div><div class='clearfix'></div><br/>"
                        data-html="true">Add</a>
```

I would like to trigger a event on button click in jquery. Code as follows,

```
$("#btntest").click(function () {
        alert("You click on button");
    });
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sridharnetha/0yumsLm0/)

What would be the reason my code is not working?

I will appreciate your help in advanced.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You can't put markup directly in to attributes like that - you need to encode it.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan my HTML is valid. have a look at documentation for bootstrap popover http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming your code renders correctly, try the code below.

```
$(function(){
   $(document).on('click',"#btntest",function () {
      alert("test button clicked");
   });
});
```

**Edited**

Take a look at my JsFiddle and see if it works
http://jsfiddle.net/jb5fexp3/

Comment: Is the html being displayed on the page? Could you put it on jsFiddle so that I can check it?

Comment: Updated my question with JSFiddle.

Comment: yeah checked that. So when you click on the "Add" button you need the click event to trigger right?

Comment: Exactly, event should be trigger by clicking on Add button.

Comment: take a look at my jsFiddle on the Edited Answer

Answer (score 3):

Check the [Bootstrap documentation on popovers](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers) again:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">
    Click to toggle popover
</button>
```

and in your JS:

```
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on("click", "#btntest", function () {
 // your code`enter code here`
})`;`
```

will bind the event on the `#btntest` elements which are not present at the time of binding event example using ajax html data set.

Comment: $(document).on("click", "#btntest, function () { will bind the event on the #btntest elements which are not present at the time of binding event example using ajax html data set.

Comment: this is usefull for me